Unable to load the Log Stream even after updating the App Service Logs on Azure
Getting an error - "Unable to open a connection to your app. This may be due to any network security groups or IP restriction rules that you have placed on your app. To use log streaming, please make sure you are able to access your app directly from your current network."
I've updated the App Service logs for my application, which is hosted on private endpoints in Azure.
Still getting the same message. Furthermore, when I try to access the log stream via "https://{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream," I'm encountering a 403 Forbidden error, even though I'm on the same private network. How can I resolve this?

Please add more details about the issue.

  def read_from_snapshot(self, schema={}, file=''):
#     try:
    if self.file_exists(file):
      df_data = df_table=spark.read.format("parquet").option("schema",schema).load(file)
    else:
      dft = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
      dft.write.mode('overwrite').option("schema",schema).parquet(file)
      df_data = df_table=spark.read.format("parquet").option("schema",schema).load(file)


Thank you for your response, but it seems like there's been a misunderstanding. The issue I'm facing is related to accessing the Log Stream for an Azure App Service that's hosted behind a private endpoint, resulting in a 403 Forbidden error. The code snippet you provided appears to be related to handling Parquet files in a Spark environment, which isn't applicable to this situation.
